# Themes aren't setting

Tags: c#, asp.net, themes, preinit

I'm using this code to change the applications theme

```
        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MasterPage m = Master;
        string theme = Session["theme"].ToString();
        Page.Theme = theme;
    }
```

The theme that is in the Session is Theme Aqua , but the theme is getting reset to standard.I'm using the devexpress themes with the devexpress controls

Also is this a good way to set the theme , is there a way u can set your theme program wide in stead of doing it page by page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the theme to an entire website by adding the

```
<pages Theme="themeName">
```

element to the `<system.web>` section of a Web.config file.

This will automatically apply the theme to all pages in your site.

Comment: And if i want to change it , just do it with the code above ?

Comment: Check if you have AutoEventWireUp = true in your page.

If you want to set the theme in code behind then set it in gobal.asax.

Comment: Also even though theme is declared in web.config it can be overridden in page directive.

Answer (score 0):

To change your theme (so you don't need to repeat it when you're creating controls) put this in your global.asax

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DevExpressHelper.Theme = "Aqua";
}
```

You can use the DevExpress tool "ThemeDeployer" to copy the theme files you want :)

Comment: DevExpressHelper? this is an external dependency, isn't it ? Can you suggest an out of the box solution ?

Comment: DevExpressHelper is part of the "DevExpress.Web.Mvc" namespace..seeing how you're using devexpress, you can just use this right?

Comment: Cant seem to find the global.asax file , it should be there right ?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC? If so, it should just be in the root of your project

Comment: If it's not there, just create it. There's a Visual Studio template for it in the Add New Item window.

Comment: alright , and with the code i posted i can change the theme ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon to declare ancestor for all pages in web.config

```
<pages pageBaseType="NicolasPierre.Page" etc
```

and then put your logic into overriding OnPreInit method. Might be useful for something else too, like prepending titles.